# How to perform changes on a ToolTip

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I want to show a `div` as `tooltip` of another `div` and I want some `input fields` like `Text Field` or `Select box` on the `div` taken as `tooltip` to grab values from End User. How can I implement this functionality using Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: see this link http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content

Comment: I have seen the link but I am not able to add any input fields to the tooltip and also when i try to place mouse over tooltip content then tooltip get disappears .

Comment: how did you try to add input fields? please post the code.

Comment: remove unnecessary code formatting

Comment: My answer shows tooltip when you hover over an image, but you can mod the example to show tooltip when hover over a div pretty easily. Good luck on your project.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is a bit complicated but the jsFiddle shows it pretty clearly.

When you hover over either image, it will read the class attribute and know from that whether to get the value of the `<select>` or of the `<input>` element.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/a313qjmh/)

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','img',function(){
    //Display tooltip of cell contents - uses #ttDiv
    t1 = this.className;
    tmp = $('#'+t1).val();
    t2 = 150;
    //$('#myOverlay').css({'background-color':'red'});
        ttDiv
        .stop(true,true)
        .dequeue()
        .html(tmp)
        .addClass('tlbInputTooltip')
        .css({'width' : t2+'px'})
        .fadeIn(200)
        ;
        ttDivON=1;
});
$(document).on('mouseleave','img',function(){
    ttDiv
    .stop(true,true)
    .dequeue()
    .html('')
    .removeClass('tlbInputTooltip')
    .fadeOut(200)
    ;
    ttDivON=0;
});
```

**css:**

```
#ttDiv{position:absolute;top:20px;left:100px;width:auto;padding:0 7px;background:wheat;display:none;z-index:2;}

.tlbInputTooltip{height:30px;width:auto;border:1px solid lightgrey;box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;display:inline-block;}
```